# apple configurator 1.7 downgrade ios from 10 to 10

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-configurator

I am using apple configurator 1.7.2. Accidentally someone upgrade IOS to version 11 as image for every no ipod touch. Is any way I can go back to version 10? I need it for run older application which not support version 11 yet. Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1):

Solved. After calling apple support this option is not allow in apple configurator.